# Drupal 8 service call from a PHP file

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want run below code of Drupal 8 in a external php file. Please guide me in achieving this.

```
$user = \Drupal::currentUser();
\Drupal::service('session_manager')->destroy();
$user->setAccount(new AnonymousUserSession());
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Seems like you want to [log out](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_logout/8.5.x) the active user.

Comment: yes I want to do the logout but from a php file say logout.php which reside in core directory

Answer (score 1):

When you access this page directly it would log out the active user. If there is no active session, it would do nothing, just displays a blank page.

Frankly, unless you must use this method, there are possibly much better *"Drupal way"* solutions if you would explain your goal in detail.

Otherwise this script works:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// Change the directory to the Drupal root.
chdir('..');

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);

\Drupal::moduleHandler()->addModule('user', 'core/modules/user');
\Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('user');

$account = \Drupal::service('authentication')->authenticate($request);
if ($account) {
  \Drupal::currentUser()->setAccount($account);
  user_logout();
}
```